# Convert duration to hours:minutes:seconds (or similar) in Rails 3 or Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a feeling there is a simple/built-in way to do this but I can't find it.

I have a duration (in seconds) in an integer and I want to display it in a friendly format.

e.g. 3600 would be displayed as "01:00:00" or "1 hour" or something.

I can do it with `time_ago_in_words(Time.zone.now+3600)` but that feels like a bit of a hack, there is no reason to add/subtract from the current time just to format this value.  Is there a `duration_in_words()` or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 94, accepted):

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html

```
distance_of_time_in_words(3600)
 => "about 1 hour"
```

Comment: thanks i looked at that but thought i had to provide two times.. what a nub!

Comment: yeah, those examples are daft

Comment: distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, to_time, ...)

Comment: Also, if you want this to be very specific and not "round" the duration, check out Radar's gem: https://github.com/radar/distance_of_time_in_words. Drop-in replacement for `distance_of_time_in_words` and you can get the rounded number by passing `vague: true` as an option.

Answer (score 212):

Summing up:

assuming that `total_seconds = 3600`

Option 1:

```
distance_of_time_in_words(total_seconds) #=> "about 1 hour"
```

Option 2:

```
Time.at(total_seconds).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S") #=> "01:00:00"
```

*Note: it overflows, eg. for `total_seconds = 25.hours.to_i` it'll return `"01:00:00"` also*

Option 3:

```
seconds = total_seconds % 60
minutes = (total_seconds / 60) % 60
hours = total_seconds / (60 * 60)

format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds) #=> "01:00:00"
```

Option 4:

```
ActiveSupport::Duration.build(total_seconds).inspect #=> "1 hour"

# OR

parts = ActiveSupport::Duration.build(total_seconds).parts
"%02d:%02d:%02d" % [parts.fetch(:hours, 0),
                    parts.fetch(:minutes, 0),
                    parts.fetch(:seconds, 0)] #=> "01:00:00"
```

Comment: The distance_of_time_in_words method is an ActionView Helper, thus needs to be called from the View (not the controller).

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html

Comment: Note that the strftime option will overflow at 24 hours. If your duration is 25 hours, it will display `01:00:00`.

Comment: this does not work for negative times, for example -1800 returns -1h 30m instead of -30m

Comment: Note that option 4 only works with `Duration.build`; if you try it with `3600.seconds` you'll get `"00:00:3600"`.

Answer (score 51):

Ruby's string `%` operator is too unappreciated and oft forgotten.

```
"%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d" % [t/86400, t/3600%24, t/60%60, t%60]
```

Given *t* is a duration in seconds, this emits a zero-padded colon-separated string including days. Example:

```
t = 123456
"%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d" % [t/86400, t/3600%24, t/60%60, t%60]
=> "01:10:17:36"
```

Lovely.

Comment: That's an odd definition of "lovely".

Comment: The `%` says, "Take the array of parameters from my right and insert them into the format string on my left." In that respect, it is similar to `printf` in C\C++ only more concise and can be used in an assignment. Yes, I call that lovely. And powerful. There are examples that would demonstrate this eloquence better, but they wouldn't answer the question. Your snark is not appreciated, btw.

Answer (score 27):

I guess you could do also something like:

```
(Time.mktime(0)+3600).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

To format it as you wish.

BTW, originally I thought of using Time.at() but seems that EPOCH time on my Ubuntu is Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 +0100 1970 and not 00:00:00 hours as I expected, and therefore if I do:

```
Time.at(3600).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Gives me 1 hour more than wanted.

Comment: ahh, might something to do because of summer time?

Comment: The only catch is if you're dealing with times more than 24 hours. In that case the hours will roll back to a low number.

Comment: For times greater than 24 hours, %j will give you the number of days (as long as it is less than 365)

Answer (score 22):

#### I use this to show time durations in my Rails Project:

1. Add a custom method to the `Integer` class. You can create a new file called `pretty_duration.rb` in the `initializers` folder:

   ```rb
   class Integer
       def pretty_duration
           parse_string = 
               if self < 3600
                   '%M:%S'
               else
                   '%H:%M:%S'
               end

           Time.at(self).utc.strftime(parse_string)
       end
   end
   ```
2. Call `seconds.pretty_duration` anywhere in your project:

   ```rb
   275.pretty_duration     # => "04:35"
   9823.pretty_duration    # => "02:43:43"
   ```

---

*This answer builds up on [Lev Lukomsky's Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9916691/1533054)*

Comment: Worked great. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 14):

This one uses the obscure `divmod` method to divide and modulo at the same time, so it handles `Float` seconds properly:

```
def duration(seconds)
  minutes, seconds = seconds.divmod(60)
  hours, minutes = minutes.divmod(60)
  days, hours = hours.divmod(24)

  "#{days.to_s.rjust(3)}d #{hours.to_s.rjust(2)}h #{minutes.to_s.rjust(2)}m #{seconds}s"
end
```

Answer (score 12):

`ActiveSupport::Duration.build` + `inspect` gives you valid results

```
 >> ActiveSupport::Duration.build(125557).inspect
 => "1 day, 10 hours, 52 minutes, and 37 seconds"
```

Comment: elegant! works well for me. result for value `75`: `1 minute and 15 seconds `

Comment: It can even be used to extract out individual parts to build a custom string. e.g. `ActiveSupport::Duration.build(125557).parts` will give `{ days: 1, hours: 10, minutes: 52, seconds: 37 }`.

Answer (score 7):

Using `Time.utc.strftime` works only for values when total number of hours **is less then 24**:

```
2.2.2 :004 > Time.at(60 * 60).utc.strftime('%H h %M m')
=> "01 h 00 m"
```

For greater values it returns incorrect results:

```
2.2.2 :006 > Time.at(60 * 60 * 24).utc.strftime('%H h %M m')
 => "00 h 00 m"
```

I suggest using the simplest method I found for this problem:

```
  def formatted_duration total_seconds
    hours = total_seconds / (60 * 60)
    minutes = (total_seconds / 60) % 60
    seconds = total_seconds % 60
    "#{ hours } h #{ minutes } m #{ seconds } s"
  end
```

You can always adjust returned value to your needs.

Answer (score 6):

Be careful with the duration longer than one day.

```
(timing/3600).to_i.to_s.rjust(2,'0') + ":"+Time.at(timing).utc.strftime("%M:%S")
```

Comment: Give an example of input/output highlighting how this solves the corner case

Answer (score 5):

An answer inspired from Lev Lukomsky's one taking advantage of ActiveSupport::Duration, and handling milliseconds (useful to benchmark code)

```
# duration in ms modulus number of ms in one second
milliseconds = duration.in_milliseconds % 1.second.in_milliseconds

# duration in seconds modulus number of seconds in one minute
seconds = (duration / 1.second) % (1.minute / 1.second)

# duration in minutes modulus number of minutes in one hour
minutes = (duration / 1.minute) % (1.hour / 1.minute)

# duration in hours modulus number of hours in one day
hours = (duration / 1.hour) % (1.day / 1.hour)

format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d", hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds) #=> "12:05:00:001"
```

Of course you can extend this easily with days, months, years, etc using related ActiveSupport methods and repeating the same structure.

Keep in mind that for too long durations, this may be inaccurate since the duration of 1 month is not fixed in number of days, and I'm not sure how AS:Duration deals with that.

Answer (score 5):

Shout out to [@joshuapinter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293280/joshua-pinter) who gave the best answer (in the form of [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175733/convert-duration-to-hoursminutesseconds-or-similar-in-rails-3-or-ruby#comment99361226_4175806)).

Use the drop-in replacement `dotiw` gem to gain more control over the accuracy of the output to suit different needs:

https://github.com/radar/distance_of_time_in_words

Sample view code:

```
%label
  Logoff after:
  - expire_in = distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, Time.now + user.custom_timeout.minutes, :only => [:minutes, :hours, :days])
  = expire_in
```

Resulting in something like this:

```
Logoff after: 1 day, 13 hours, and 20 minutes
```

Comment: Note that you can also use `dotiw` to generate other formats, e.g.: `DOTIW::TimeHash.new(1.days + 2.hours + 3.minutes + 4.seconds, nil).to_hash.each_value.map { |v| format('%02d', v) }.join(':')` produces `01:02:03:04`. (This particular format gets a bit unreadable beyond days, though.)

Answer (score 3):

Just to throw in my 2 cents:

```
Time.at(i).utc.strftime((i < 3600) ? '%-M minutes and %-S seconds' : '%-H hours, %-M minutes, and %-S seconds')
```

Built off of Xiao Bin's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here a simple solution using divmod and map:

```
    hours = 3.5456
    value = (hours*60).divmod(60).map{ |a| "%02d"%[a.floor] }.join(":")
    => "03:32"
```

Comment: Please add some context to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to option 4 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9916691/1224499) but deals with duration going over a day

```
duration = ActiveSupport::Duration.build(total_seconds)
%i(hours minutes seconds).map { |part| "%02d" % (duration.parts.fetch(part, 0) + (part == :hours ? duration.in_days.to_i * 24 : 0)) }.join(':')
```

Comment: clarified answer