# Convert the total seconds to time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

My total seconds is `125557`

when i tried to convert the seconds into "H:M:S" by using

```
Time.at(125557).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

it gives like `10:52:37`

but i want actually like `34:52:37` (adding one day to 10:52:37 )

Answer (score 8):

Well, given that `34:52:37` is not a valid time string, it makes little sense to use time parsing/conversion libraries for this. Better to calculate it manually. `div` and `mod` are your best friends here. Take a look:

```
secs = 125557
secs_in_an_hour = 3600

hours, secs = secs.divmod(secs_in_an_hour)
hours # => 34
secs # => 3157 # This now contains only minutes and seconds, no full hours
```

It should be quite easy to evolve this to a full working solution.

Comment: Such answers are the reasons I admire you. Always humble and bent towards helping newcomers like me. Thanks for being on SO. Keep it up. :)

Comment: @Surya: at 10k rep, you can hardly qualify as a newcomer. But thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
total_seconds = 125557

seconds = total_seconds % 60
minutes = (total_seconds / 60) % 60
hours = total_seconds / (60 * 60)

format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [ruby-duration gem](https://github.com/peleteiro/ruby-duration) if you want to deal with weeks, days, hours, minutes, and seconds more easily.

```
d = Duration.new(125557)
=> #<Duration:0x007f84180758e8 @days=1, @hours=10, @minutes=52, @negative=false, @seconds=37, @total=125557, @weeks=0>
d.total_hours
=> 34
d.total_minutes
=> 2092
```

Answer (score 2):

Since **Rails 6.1.0** you can do:

```rb
1.day.in_hours # => 24.0
3600.seconds.in_hours # => 1.0
```

Documentation: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_hours

Comment: This is super useful! No Gem needed

Answer (score 1):

I posted my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62562658/2970582
`ActiveSupport::Duration` + `inspect` gives you valid results